# How to open Visual Studio in WSL2 and other apps?

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 on wsl2. I know that with the command 'code .' you can open VS Code, but I want to know is there a commands for all Apps that u can open them from wsl2 terminal, like for example command for Visual Studio?

Comment: Just a heads-up - I'd recommend being careful with this type of question on Stack Overflow that isn't directly programming related.  I think this one is borderline since you ask about "All apps, such as Visual Studio" (a programming tool, obviously).  But really, this is a more general question that would be a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Okey sir got it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WSL has "[Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#interop)" enabled, which allows you to run/launch any Windows executable from within WSL.  Also by default, WSL appends the Windows path to your WSL path (also controlled in the same Interop section of `/etc/wsl.confg`).

So as long as the Windows application is in the path, `appname.exe` will work.  For instance, `notepad.exe` will launch Notepad.

The reason that you don't need the `.exe` with VSCode is because the Windows version provides a shell script (`code`) that is designed to work with WSL.

For apps that are not on the path, you can either edit the WSL path (in, for instance, your `.bashrc`) or provide the full path like:

```
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Windows\ Photo\ Viewer/ImagingDevices.exe
```

Note that you need to account for the difference between Linux/POSIX path and the Windows equivalent.  For instance:

```
notepad.exe ~/test.txt
```

... will not work, since Notepad won't understand the Linux path.  WSL provides the `wslpath` command to translate paths:

```
notepad.exe $(wslpath -w ~/test.txt)
```

or

```
notepad.exe '\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\test.txt'
```

**Please note:** This is a bad example, just to make it easy to understand. Do not use notepad.exe to edit Linux files, as Notepad will add CRLF (DOS line-endings) which Linux apps will not handle properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to run Visual Studio 2022 from WSL2 this way:

```bash
# Path to Visual Studio executable
VSRUN='C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Visual Studio 2022.lnk'

function open_in_vs() {
   # Take first passed argument and generate absolute path
   FIRST_ARG=`realpath $1`
   # Convert path (which is now in Unix style) to Windows path
   PATH_TO_FILE=`wslpath -w $FIRST_ARG`
   # Run process using PowerShell
   powershell.exe "Start-Process '${VSRUN}' '${PATH_TO_FILE}'"
}

# open_in_vs ./testfile.txt

# This adds an `openvs` alias you can use in your terminal to open any file in VS
alias openvs=open_in_vs
```