# Opening WSL files in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, wsl-2, visual-studio-2022

TL;DR: Has anyone found a way to open **folders** in WSL2 using Visual Studio 2022?

Context: I am developing a C/C++ Linux software. Currently, I am using VisualStudio Code to open and edit source files. Now, I am way more efficient with Visual Studio 2022 and I cannot find a way to open **folders** inside of WSL2. (Single files work, but that is nearly not good enough for a proper workflow).

I have tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66568560/16076456), but it does not do what I need.

Further, according to [this MS devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/build-and-debug-c-with-wsl-2-distributions-and-visual-studio-2022/), quote:
*"Our C++ cross-platform support in Visual Studio assumes that all source files originate in the Windows file system."* This is not the case for me, my files originate in WSL2 and making them originate in Windows would be a hassle that would outweigh the benefits gained from working with VS2022.

Note: I only want to write code this way. Building and running the software is done somewhere else.

Anyone managed to make this work?

Comment: if you are only using VS 2022 for writing code (not using any IDE features) wouldn't VS Code be a better option here?

Comment: I would have tried to basically configure VS2022 in a way that would allow me to further simplify my development. Being able to open a folder would be necessary for that attempt to even make sense. And yes, until that somehow becomes possible, I will stick to VS Code.

Comment: vscode is useless for c/c++ - no refactoring tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible at this moment according to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/debug-your-net-core-apps-in-wsl-2-with-visual-studio/#comment-7947

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-debug-dotnet-core-project-in-wsl/1554569

The feedback was from Oct 19, 2021. I am very disappointed.

> Currently the extension only support opening projects that are stored in the windows disks (it leverages WSLs automount feature). If opening from a network location is something you need please add it as a suggestion on Developer Community.

Comment: I see "A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Thank you for providing valuable feedback which has helped improve the product." - has the situation improved?

Comment: REALLY! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes
but I can't find any related to WSL in 17.7